# What programming language is prefered for a simple program like this?

Tags: user-interface, programming-languages, web-scraping

I'm planning to make a simple program which will basically web scrape and provide that information into a simple gui.

There'll be notification for new info, and a simple database to store history, favorite and such

What programming language is suitable/good for simple task like this? And can you please give a starting point about making the program?

I'm currently only using python, trying to find out how to make the gui. If anyone can give some resources, it'll be super usefull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best if you pick the programming language you know best.

Since you mentioned Python, you could use PyGTK, wxPython or similar GUI frameworks for Python.

I would personally do it in C# since the GUI designer in Visual Studio is one of the best I've used, but this is entirely up to you.

The choice of language depends on your experience with each language: In C++ it takes time, in Python it might be uncomfortable and in C# it might be hard to get it running on other platforms.

SQLite would be an excellent choice for the database. It is easy to set up and use in any language.

**Links:**

http://www.wxpython.org/

http://www.pygtk.org/

https://sqlite.org/